# The automatic updates for my Kernel (3.16.0-30) are giving an older version (3.13.0-100)

Tags: 14.04, kernel

Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS:

I inherited an Ubuntu server that does not appear to be getting the correct automatic updates for latest Ubuntu patches.

My installed version of the kernel is 3.16.0-30. I'm getting 3.13.0-xx instead.

How do I get this fixed up so I can start receiving updates for 3.16.x instead of 3.13.x.

Example:

```
$ uname -r
**3.16.0-30-generic**

dpkg --list 'linux-image*'

ii  linux-image-**3.13.0-100**-generic       3.13.0-100.147            amd64                     
ii  linux-image-**3.13.0-101**-generic       3.13.0-101.148            amd64                     
ii  linux-image-**3.13.0-103**-generic       3.13.0-103.150            amd64                     


/boot# ls -ltra
total 62338
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   178680 Mar 12  2014 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   178176 Mar 12  2014 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   176500 Mar 12  2014 memtest86+.bin
-rw-------  1 root root  6345104 Jan 15  2015 vmlinuz-3.16.0-30-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  3511040 Jan 15  2015 System.map-3.16.0-30-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   171768 Jan 15  2015 config-3.16.0-30-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1207386 Jan 15  2015 abi-3.16.0-30-generic
drwx------  2 root root    12288 Dec  3  2015 lost+found
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 20686864 Oct  7 10:55 initrd.img-3.16.0-30-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  5849616 Dec  6 12:22 vmlinuz-3.13.0-106-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  3399674 Dec  6 12:22 System.map-3.13.0-106-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   166061 Dec  6 12:22 config-3.13.0-106-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1166834 Dec  6 12:22 abi-3.13.0-106-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 20506058 Dec 20 06:35 initrd.img-3.13.0-106-generic
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 Dec 20 10:39 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     1024 Dec 20 10:39 grub
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root     4096 Dec 20 10:39 ..
```

Comment: Is this a VPS ?

Comment: Using `apt-cache policy` or similar tool, check which version(s) of `linux-generic*` you have installed. Maybe it's an ancient package trying to pull this in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get updates for the 3.16 kernel. It is not supported any more.
You have 2 options.

1. Uninstall 3.16 kernel packages and use the 3.13 kernel. It will be supported till the end of Ubuntu 14.04.
2. Install the 4.4 kernel by running

   ```
   sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial
   ```

This kernel will get updates till April 2019 as well.

Comment: If you look at the `dpkg -l` output in the question, OP does not have any 3.16 kernel packages installed, which makes me suspect it's a VPS with the kernel managed by the host.

Comment: That may be true. Lets's see if OP appears again.

Comment: @fkraiem 
thanks for your response. This is a VM, but I do not know if it's a VPS. Though I never heard someone here refer to it as such. The kernel is old yes, but I'd rather move forward with installing a new kernel as I would rather not revisit this.

Comment: @KenO'Connell The question here is whether you are able to use a new kernel at all, or whether you have to stick with the one provided (and, hopefully, maintained) by your host. You say this is a VM; what kind of VM? Just a VirtualBox running on your personal system, or what?

Comment: @fkraiem -The VMs are ESXi5.5

Comment: @KenO'Connell What is surprising is that you are running a 3.16 kernel, but you seem to have no 3.16 kernel packages installed. Are you sure your output of `dpkg --list` is correct? What about `dpkg -l | grep linux` or `ls /boot`, do they show any 3.16 kernel?

Comment: @fkraiem Yes, the output of the orig dpkg command in OP is correct. The output of  the 'dpkg -l | grep linux' command shows much more about what was installed, but it's all 3.13.*. When looking in my /boot dir, I do find the orig 3.16 
-rw-------  1 root root  6345104 Jan 15  2015 vmlinuz-3.16.0-30-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  3511040 Jan 15  2015 System.map-3.16.0-30-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   171768 Jan 15  2015 config-3.16.0-30-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1207386 Jan 15  2015 abi-3.16.0-30-generic

Comment: @KenO'Connell Okay then you can add the output of `ls /boot` to the question, it is significant.

Comment: @KenO'Connell And about how to go rom there, basically follow @Pilot6's answer, except that since your 3.16 kernel is not part of any package, if you want to remove it you can just `rm` the files in `/boot`.

Comment: @fkraiem Thank you. I'm concerned to move forward with installing 4.4 due to your comment  "he question here is whether you are able to use a new kernel at all". How can I determine if moving to this version will be a problem?

Comment: @Pilot6 I also wanted to thank you for your post, which should be the accepted answer here. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @KenO'Connell This comment was prompted by the fact that you were running a 3.16 kernel that seemed to not be installed (which could mean that your system disregarded the installed kernels), but in fact the 3.16 is installed, albeit in a non-standard way, so that does not apply.